# android - how to reuse items already populated in fragments in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

In my application I have a ViewPager which is populated with 5 fragments.

1. ALL
2. Ongoing.
3. Paused
4. Error
5. Complete

All these fragments populate same list_item in a recyclerview from a database table using CursorRecyclerviewAdapter(same adapter is used by all fragments) and it also starts background tasks for each item and attach listener to it.

Basically all fragments are same, each fragment filters items according to its state.

The problem is,

For example item1 is ongoing so it should only be populated in ALL and Ongoing fragments. But each item also has a listener attached to it to update progressbar according to the task progress(The task is managed by a service.).

But whenever new fragment is created it creates new item to populate recyclerview and it also create a new listener for each item.

So how can I just use viewpager as filter to filter items already populated in ALL fragment and the use the same item with already attached listener to populate appropriate fragments?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rubycell.apps.internet.download.manager&hl=en

application as example.

Comment: Is there a remote possibility that you would consider a non-ViewPager with Fragments approach for this?

Comment: Yes I would, but how? I want it to be a swipe filter.

Comment: Simple don't use ViewPager at all, just create one Fragment which holds the RecyclerView and to filter the displayed items using your Adapter.